# Is this thread-safe?

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile

I want to make my class thread-safe without large overhead.
The instances will be seldom used concurrently, but it may happen.
Most of the class is immutable, there's only one mutable member used as a cache:

```
private volatile SoftReference<Map<String, Something>> cache
    = new SoftReference(null);
```

which gets assigned *in the constructor (not shared)* like

```
Map<String, Something> tmp = new HashMap<String, Something>();
tmp.put("a", new Something("a");
tmp.put("b", new Something("b");
cache = new SoftReference(tmp);
```

After the assignment, the map gets never modified.

It's no problem, when two threads compute the cache in parallel, since the value will be the same.
The additional overhead of the word done twice is acceptable.

When a thread wouldn't see the value computed by another tread, it'd compute it unnecessary, and this is acceptable.
This wouldn't happen because of volatile.
When a thread sees value computed by another tread, it's fine.

*The only possible problem would be a thread seeing inconsistent state (e.g. a partly filled map).
Can this happen?*

#### Notes:

1. I really want the whole map being softly referenced, there's no use for a map using soft keys or values here.
2. I know about ConcurrentHashMap and will maybe use it anyway, but I'm curious, if using volatile only works.

Comment: Where do you assign `cache`. Is it shared by threads?

Comment: No, it's done in the constructor and not shared.

Comment: this will not compile even. so on, if you read only the SoftReference it will be thread safe and recreate on miss. i mean cache = new SoftReference(tmp), if you do need to check it on every get

Comment: forgot: i'd advise to just initialize cache =new SoftReference(null); *I know about ConcurrentHashMap and will maybe use it anyway, but I'm curious, if using volatile only works.* it does; java.lang.Class caches methods and fields in a similar way

Comment: (Note you will probably get all your active threads seeing the reference cleared at once. You might want to try some double-checked shenanigans (but be careful out there).)

Comment: Since you only modify the `cache` field in the constructor you should make it `final` instead:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#64946

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The only possible problem would be a
>   thread seeing inconsistent state (e.g.
>   a partly filled map). Can this happen?

No. Actions performed within a thread must be performed as if they had been executed in order. Writing a volatile variable happens-before any read of that value. Hence, initialization of the map happens-before any thread reading the reference to the map from the field.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using a soft reference is that you can lose the whole map/cache after a GC.  This means the performance of your application can be hit very hard.  You are better off using a cache with an eviction policy so that you never have this problem.

The volatile doesn't make any operation safe here.

You haven't shown all your code, perhaps we could offer some suggestion on how you could improve your code e.g. your sample code should compile ;)

Comment: @Peter, in my experience SoftRef have really decent performance, their life expectancy is based on the free heap available (it's documented as well), they are close to free compared to anything w/ eviction policy. Sun is using them quite liberally as well.

Comment: @bestsss, I agree the overhead is small. Sun tends to use them with object which are not expensive to replace.  The more benefit you get from your cache, the more expensive it is to just drop it. It does add some complexity to your code as you have to check various null values and recreate the HashMap as required.

Comment: "The volatile doesn't make any operation safe here." What do you mean by "operation"? What do you mean by "safe"? At the very least, volatile will guarantee that the cache is visible to other threads.

Comment: as for volatile after assignment, it ensure the rest of the CPU can see the changes

Comment: *"The problem with using a soft reference is that you can lose the whole map/cache after a GC."* - Yes, I know. The cache is needed during the construction, where it gets protected by a strong reference. Thereafter it may or may not be useful, that's why I do it this way. No eviction policy can help, any missing element would lead to a wrong result, only the whole Map is useful.

Comment: Without volatile, it will be visible to other threads in a short period of time.  Before assigning to the cache, you need to check if it need to be created/recreated, between the check and the creation, another thread could create the same cache, with or without volatile.

Comment: @Peter, imo the behavior that N threads can recreate cache and dump is (usually) considered acceptable, unless there is very high contention and the needed object (cache) is really large. Then you might need to allow not so many threads (doing w/ one can cause starvation after a very bad thread schedule)

Comment: *"Without volatile, it will be visible to other threads in a short period of time."* - Some random portion of the map would be visible, which needn't be a consistent map at all.

Comment: @maaartinus, you can actually keep the `cache` variable non-volatile but then you need some volatile write (or `unsafe.putObjectVolatile` better), after finishing initialization of the map and after constructing `new SoftReference(tmp)` [or just `unsafe.putObjectVolatile(this, seedOfCache`, tmp) to set `cache`]. That derails the topic too much though, so I am not going to elaborate further.

Comment: OK, that's fine. Most probably I'll do it differently -- for a reason not related to this question. I understand `volatile` better now, and that's important.

Comment: If the field is not volatile, you will either see the complete map or not at all, you are only protecting the first reference lookup of the the SoftReference.  The reason I queried this is that on one hand you have a reference which will randomly disappear (the soft reference) but you want to place some guarantees on when it will appear. Its a bit like insisting on using StrictMath.random() instead of Math.random().